# Can't increase timeout on nginx with php-fpm

Tags: php, nginx, fpm

My Nginx refuses to increase the timeout for a request from the default of 60 seconds.

I've already set the following parameters, but the server still gives me 504 after 60 seconds:

```
fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
proxy_read_timeout 300s;
client_header_timeout 300s;
client_max_body_size 200m;
client_body_timeout 300s;
send_timeout 300s;
```

Interestingly enough, setting the values to 30 seconds works, and the request times out after 30 seconds. The request_terminate_timeout in PHP-fpm is also set to 300 seconds.

Which parameters do I have to set to get it further than 60 seconds?

Comment: Did you also set [max_execution_time](https://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) in php.ini? If not, try that (don't forget to restart php-fpm after modifying php.ini)

Comment: i already set max_execution_time in php.ini to 300 and request_terminate_timeout to 300 in www.conf and i'm still getting 504 gateway timeout error

Answer (score 4):

Have you added the following directives at the end of the 'http' section?

```
http {
    <...>
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/.conf;

    proxy_send_timeout 180s;
    proxy_read_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180s;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180s;
}
```

You may also need to restart your nginx server after this.

Another possible cause to why nothing changes for you is that you might edit the wrong file, but that I doubt. :)

To verify the path, both `nginx -t` and `nginx -V` would print out the default nginx config file path.

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout

Comment: yes i already did it but i have problem with that directory. there's no file inside conf.d
[Pic1](https://imgur.com/WmyQjcP)
[Pic2](https://imgur.com/3acU6aQ)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson oops, idk why I wrote fpm.

Comment: @fuher If you try to use nginx -t to verify your config path, you might find it

Comment: i checked the path and it's saying "--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"

Comment: @Fuher what happends if you set `request_terminate_timeout=300s` in the php-fpm config? Usually located in /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf

Comment: i set request_terminate_timeout=300s in /etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf and return to me a error `Job for php7.2-fpm.service failed because the control process exited with error code.`. `ERROR: [/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf:26] unknown entry 'request_terminate_timeout'`

Comment: @Fuher are you using docker, vagrant or something similar? If so, try to restart it along with the php-fpm process as request_terminate_timeout is a valid entry.